# Getting an exception when using 'util.promisify` to perform telnet

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, angular-promise

Able to perform successful telnet operation to the server `linux234` at port `2345.` This means the following code should display output as `0`

However, the code output is returning an exception `TypeError: Cannot read property 'write' of undefined at Socket.connect (net.js:901:12) at Promise (internal/util.js:274:30) at new Promise (<anonymous>) at internal/util.js:273:12`

```
const net = require('net');
const util = require('util');

let HOST = 'linux234';
let PORT = 2345;

let ErrCode = 1;

let client = new net.Socket();

let connect = util.promisify(client.connect);

async function performTelnet() {
    try {
        let data = await connect(PORT, HOST);
        ErrCode = 0;
        console.log('Client received: ' + data);
        if (data.toString().endsWith('exit')) {
            client.destroy();
        }
    }
    catch (ex) {
        ErrCode = -1;
        console.log(ex);
    }
}

performTelnet().then(() => {
    console.log(ErrCode)
}
)
```

Comment: Promisify is used to promisify functions with a pattern like `somefunc(arg1, arg2, function(err, result) { ... })` - `socket.connect` does not follow this pattern

Comment: Can you please let me what changes I need to make in my code? If possible, please provide updated code